# Cannot make html page responsive using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am trying to make two sections called, get started and about us responsive, and I am a beginner at using bootstrap so I am making some mistakes.

I tried to make the get started section work, but the buttons are not responsive at all. The about us section, I used 2 images for laptop and cellphone but even that is creating some problems as the margin doesn't stay the same for picture and image, so need help.

**HTML Code:**

```
   <section class="cont_1">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Get started!</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <p>Now that you now the process it's time to check out recent offer.
          it only take 5 min to get ypur loan or invest</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 borrow"> <a href="#">Borrow</a> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 borrow"> <a style="background-color:#fff; color:#66cccc; border: 1px solid #66cccc;" href="#">invest</a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

    <section class="about">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="about_tx">
        <h4>About Us</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> <img src="img/corporate3.jpg"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about_tx"> <img src="img/corporate3.jpg"> </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .cont_1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: #676767;
    padding: 82px 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;
    border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
}
.cont_1 h2 {
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.cont_1 .col-md-7 p {
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 23px;
}
/*.cont_1 .col-md-2 a{font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:28px;background:#66cccc; color:#FFF;padding:14px 30px 17px 37px; display:block; margin-bottom:10px;}
.cont_1 .col-md-2:last-child a {background: #fff; border: 1px solid #66cccc; color: #66cccc; display:block;}*/

.cont_1 .col-md-2 a {
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    background: #66cccc;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 6px 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.cont_1 .col-md-2 a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #66cccc;
    color: #66cccc;
}

/******************************
*******************************
*********ABOUT US***************
*******************************
******************************/

.about {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.about_tx {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.about_tx h4 {
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.about_tx p {
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
}
.about_tx img {
    width: 100%;
    height:80%;
    float: left;
}
.about_tx img:last-child {
    margin-top: 113px;
}
.about img {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 49%;
}
.about .col-md-6 img {
    display: none;
}

/******************************
*******************************
*********RESPONSIVE DIV********
*******************************
******************************/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

    .borrow {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0;
    }

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .about img {
        display: none;
    }
    .about .col-md-6 img {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .col-md-2 > a {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .copy_tx p {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .sm {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .cont_1 .col-md-2 a {
        padding: 6px 25px;
    }
}
```

If there is a very easy way of making it responsive with just bootstrap classes please do help me out, and is it possible using just one image and making it responsive for about us? And the files are also attached if you want to take a look at it.[File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzcs14pn8h5a2b3/stack.zip?dl=0)

Comment: can you add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @HarshSanghani I added the file at top for download

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your section (cont_1) by below:

```
<section class="cont_1">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Get started!</h2>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <p>Now that you now the process it's time to check out recent offer.
          it only take 5 min to get ypur loan or invest</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 borrow"> <a href="#">Borrow</a> </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 borrow"> <a style="background-color:#fff; color:#66cccc; border: 1px solid #66cccc;" href="#">invest</a> </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do I change anything on the CSS? since that will affect it

Comment: I tried it, but the buttons still close up, only way to do it is put a margin right but then that makes it huge margin on the cellphone view.

Comment: you don't need to change anything at css level.. "button still close up" means? do you want the buttons to be displayed in same width in cellphone?

Comment: when I start re sizing the screen, the buttons attach together, you can check in the file I uploaded, I need space between the buttons when I go from laptop to tablet screen..

Comment: try using "btn" css class in your <a> links for Borrow and Invest...  "btn" is a bootstrap class for styling the buttons

Comment: I tried using button classes, but both the buttons are attached together

Comment: which browser you are using? I can see some spaces between the buttons while resizing

Comment: I am using googlechrome, here is very small space, since its buttons they should be further apart.